# cannot find symbol class View, MockMVC, etc

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I'm getting compilation errors now that I am trying to use junit and mockito to unit test my application.

I know my test is not finished, but I can't even get passed the build due to maven not being able to see these class symbols that should be coming from Mockito.

Here is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>ets</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.ets</groupId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.</groupId>

<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>service</name>
<description>Informatica Service API</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.boot.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <deployment-artifacts-plugin.version>1.0.0</deployment-artifacts-plugin.version>
    <aws.sdk.version>1.11.313</aws.sdk.version>
    <junit-platform.version>5.3.1</junit-platform.version>

</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.53</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0.pr1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.forge</groupId>
            <artifactId>deployment-artifacts-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${deployment-artifacts-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attach</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

Here is the test

```
class

import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
    import org.mockito.Mock;
    import com.service.api.LinuxController;
    import com.service.services.LinuxCommandService;

    public class LinuxControllerTest {
@InjectMocks
LinuxController controller;

@Mock
LinuxCommandService linuxCommandService;

@Mock
View mockView;


MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
            .setSingleView(mockView)
            .build();
}
@Test
public void testRunCommand() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/linux/command"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    //        .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/customer/list"));

}}
```

Here is the error.

```
BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  56.753 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-19T10:02:20-04:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project service: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/guy/Desktop/git_repos/local-svc/src/test/java/LinuxControllerTest.java:[16,5] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class View
    [ERROR]   location: class LinuxControllerTest
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/guy/Desktop/git_repos/local-svc/src/test/java/LinuxControllerTest.java:[19,5] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class MockMvc
    [ERROR]   location: class LinuxControllerTest
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/guy/Desktop/git_repos/local-svc/src/test/java/LinuxControllerTest.java:[21,6] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class Before
    [ERROR]   location: class LinuxControllerTest
    [ERROR] /C:/Users/guy/Desktop/git_repos/local-svc/src/test/java/LinuxControllerTest.java:[30,6] cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   class Test
    [ERROR]   location: class LinuxControllerTest
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
```

Comment: None of the classes the compiler complains about are related to `Mockito` . I assume they belong to `spring`(`View`, `MockMvc`) and `junit` (`Test`, `Before`).

Comment: Normally I would define a `sourceDirectory` and `testSourceDirectory` in the pom, how did you define those?

Comment: I did not define them, I just included one pom.xml. 

Do you have an example of this anywhere

Comment: Check [`here`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-model/maven.html). Its defined in the `build` section.

Answer (score 0):

can you please add all the missing import statement.

Answer (score 0):

All four symbols mentioned in the error are not imported in your LinuxControllerTest.java file. You need to add the imports:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must inject dependency.

```
@Autowired 
MockMvc mockMvc;
```